# Switching between different thematic maps of same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, thematic-map

I have a layer with a lot of information. For all the different fields I would need to generate different thematic maps.

Is there a way to generate these maps and switch between them (for presentation purposes)?

My workaround was to export the layout to image file. However, I would need different QGIS functionalities while presenting. I got the tip to use atlas but I am not sure how I can generate these thematic maps from same layer. Another workaround could be to make copies of this layer but not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: You can try the QGIS Atlas Tool

Comment: Multiple layer styles or map themes? It is easy to change between them.

Comment: one very easy way would be to make copies of your layer and style them differently. You can then just (de)select the respective layers and everything else remains the same.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry I need to make myself more clear. My layer file has a column  population, a column average income and a colum. I would like to make thematic maps using symbology colours based on all 3 columns, but with different colours and grouping (graduated and other categorised). But I would like to show this within QGIS. Making copies is for sure the easiest way. I thought there is a more elegant version. Layer Sale Loader I think can show different styles but on same values, right?

Comment: A qml file stores exactly this information. It stores the type of symbology used (categorized, graduated) and which column was used etc. Read [here](https://woostuff.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/all-the-q-files/): "... It contains an export of the style information, including labels, from a layer. ... QML files are handy if you have one, or more, layers but have a collection of different style that you want to apply to them"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Layer Style Loader plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LayerStyleLoader/#plugin-about) I have developed a while ago. Within a root folder create multiple subfolders. Each subfolder needs to contain `qml` file(s) with the same name like your layer(s) is / are called within your project. When pressing `Load Layer Styles` the layer(s) will immediately change the styling based on the corresponding `qml` file(s) within the subfolder.
You can save your styling as `qml` in the Layer Properties > Style > Save Style.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Finally I managed to try. The plugin works perfect for me. Thank you all for your support. Much appreciated

Comment: Servus Bernd, Your plugin working perfect for me on Windows machine. Using it all day long. But I have an issue on my Mac. Python Error says:    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/xxxxxx/iCloudDrive/Documents/01/GIS/QField/cloud/Wabi_v2/'. I wonder where it gets the path (well from my windows machine), but not sure why it is there on MAC. Thanks in advance.